# Can “to punt something” mean “not to do something”?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Somewhere, I picked up the use of “to punt something” (or “to punt on something”) to mean “choosing not to do something” or “choosing not to do something now”. Examples:

> The weather looks bad, let’s punt (on) the bike ride.

But I am having doubt that this is a correct use of the term, and I can find hardly any related references, so I am seeking clarification.

Also, is it *to put something* or *to punt on something*, or both?

Some of the possibly related references I found are:

- > Let’s extend all the tax cuts and punt again. ([source](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/politics-july-dec12-cbo_08-22/))
- [The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/punt) says:

  > 2. Informal To cease doing something; give up: *Let's punt on this and try something else*.
- Multiple slang dictionarlies ([this one](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/punt) and [this one](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/punt.html)), which maybe indicates that this used in computer jargon, but not in general English.
- According to [Yahoo answers](https://www.yahoo.com/news/the-most-annoying--pretentious-and-useless-business-jargon.html), it is also business jargon.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/punt) lists it, marking it as informal and AmE.

Comment: @Edwin: Weird. It seems a very counter-intuitive usage to me, given that *to **take a** punt on X* is a much more common idiom meaning *to **try** X* (metaphorically place a bet on it), which is effectively the complete opposite.

Comment: @FF But wasn't it your grandad who said something similar about 'cleave' (it might have been Anne).

Comment: @tchrist, fixed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is from "punting" a rugby ball, or American football. In Britain we talk about "kicking (an idea/proposal) into touch" - same sort of thing.

Comment: @WS2: I guessed that, but although I don't know (or *wish* to know! :) much about American football, I thought punting the ball in that context meant kicking it forward - but not *taking your eye off the ball.* By which I mean the ball is very much "still in play", rather than *kicked into the long grass*.

Comment: @Edwin: Certainly not my grandad, since I never met either of them. Personally I'd only ever use *cleave [unto]= unite [with]* when facetiously mocking archaic biblical texts, but then again I'd rarely use *cleave = split* anyway - it's really just for poetic contexts, not conversational ones.

Comment: Anyway, my *personal* opinion is it's a bad idea to use *punt* in OP's sense, simply because not everyone will know the usage (and at least *some* of them might completely misinterpret it in contexts that aren't quite as self-explanatory as OP's example). But since this (imho "perverse") sense is in fact listed in dictionaries, I think it's at best a matter of opinion whether OP should consider it "correct".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, from what I remember about playing rugby (linked inextricably among my 1950s grammar-school recollections with things like corporal punishment) and occasional tunings in to the Six Nations matches, "punting" is something that is mostly done to get your team out of trouble, by getting the ball upfield quickly. It does often amount to kicking for touch.

Comment: By itself, no, that wording won't work.

“To punt something… ” is always to put it up for consideration, whether that means merely for debate, or for betting on.

Your “not to do something” would require not simply "to punt…" but necessarily "to punt (it) somewhere (else)…"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the OED it is a North American colloquial term, which derives from that meaning of *punt* which is to do with kicking a Rugby ball, or American football.

It is sense 4a of third meaning of the verb *punt* - to "kick after dropping [the ball] from the hands, and before it touches the ground".

> 4. N. Amer. colloq.
>      a. intr. To give up, back out; to defer or avoid taking action or responsibility, to ‘pass the buck’.
>
> 1966   Chicago Tribune 10 Nov. (North Neighborhood News section) 3 a
>   1/4   I've never been a fashion commentator before so I'll punt.
>
> 1972   N.Y. Times 16 Apr. 42/3   When Jerry saw that he was not going
>   to run things, he punted.
>
> 1982   Christian Sci. Monitor (Nexis) 12 Aug.   The board doesn't
>   really seem to know how to handle the de-icing problem and has punted
>   on a major issue that could have strong bearing on protecting
>   passengers next winter.
>
> 2002   Yahoo! Internet Life Feb. 100/2   Sometimes it's easier to punt
>   and assign the whole damn problem to a computer.

Comment: Yes, In American football the team punts the ball when they decide to give up trying for a touchdown and give the ball to the other team. The idea is to kick the ball as far down field as they can to make sure the other team is as far from scoring as possible when the ball is turned over to them.

Comment: @Jim Not entirely dissimilar to tactics in rugby. Interestingly, the equivalent metaphor in Britain is "kicking for touch" (i.e. to get the ball over the touchline, and hence out of play). *Are you still intending to move house? No, we've kicked the idea into touch for the time being*.

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert, but it is easy to overthink these things. I am the sister of three brothers. One of my brothers just texted that he was comfortable “punting“ on our summer house rental because of the pandemic. In this case he was referring to accepting the negotiation with the house owner to forfeit the deposit, unless the owner can rent to somebody else, because it is too risky to congregate like that at a time like this.

At first I thought it was a typo for “bunting“, the baseball term. After looking it up, though, I think that he did mean punting, and that both terms mean approximately the same thing: to choose the less risky move; to take a small amount of progress rather than the likelihood of a bigger loss; in a sense, trying to keep your options open. And that is what we are doing with the summer house rental. We are accepting the loss of the 50% deposit, rather than risk the family inadvertently contracting covid 19. And we are not demanding the return of that 50% deposit, because we are going to want to rent the same house next year, and want to stay on good terms with the owner. For the same reason, the owner is forfeiting the rest of the rental payment from us.

I think that “punting“ is not really meant to mean choosing not to do anything. It means taking the less risky move, and trying to keep your options open.

Comment: This contains the essence of a good answer. Replacing the personal blog part with cited referrences to an authoritative source (online dictionary of phrase or other) would be preferred here, it's just the way we work. Enjoy the [tour] and when you have some free-time, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0):

In Australian colloquial language, to "take a punt" means "give it a shot, give it a go", to "take a chance and do it".

Comment: See Fumble Fingers' second comment: it's British (Commonwealth) English.

Answer (score 0):

To me, as an I.T. person, *punting* means when you ask for support on an issue, and the response is lazy and asks you to perform actions that are so vague, all encompassing, and unhelpful (like *"Check the network.")*.  They just put the onus back on you with no meaningful input.

*"I asked for assistance on this issue, and they just punted it back to me."*

Answer (score -1):

"Punt something" more tends to bet on something. Another example. When NYC Council urges to remove Jefferson Thomas's statue, NY Post says in its editorial: "Mayor Bill de Blasio has opted to **punt the issue** to another commission led by his wife, charged with pondering a whole new wave of monument removals, building renamings, etc. — which adds up to stalling until he can see how the wind is blowing in the long term."

Comment: Not my downvote, but I can understand the reason for it. Here, 'punt the issue to another commission' means, essentially, 'pass the buck'. Nothing to do with the 'take a punt on' = 'bet on' usage. More akin to 'kick the issue into touch'.

Comment: The answer does seem to be contradicting itself.